# Testing config / system env getters

Tags: elixir

I have a function called `Auth.app_id` which tries to read `app_id` from app's config first, and if missing will look for system envs.

What is the best practice to test such function ? Surely using `Application.put_env` and `System.put_env` inside test beforehand is very bad practice, as we're operating with global variables and async testing will be impossible.

```
test "getting config variables" do
  Application.put_env(:appname, :app_id, "123")
  assert Auth.app_id === "123"
end

test "getting env variables" do
  System.put_env("APPNAME_APP_ID", "111")
  assert Auth.app_id === "111"
end
```

This is how getter function looks internally:

```
def app_id do
  Application.get_env(
    :appname,
    :app_id,
    System.get_env("APPNAME_APP_ID")
  )
end
```

The problems is that I have quite a few functions using these getters, like returning url with app_id as param.

Comment: I know it's a hair-splitting detail but those aren't really "getters".  Not in the OO sense. In fact you could generalize that `app_id` function by not hiding the details inside of it but rather passing the values to get retrieved as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way around the fact that those variables are global (without looking at mocking). My suggestion would be to either not run the tests concurrently (not using `async: true` in `use ExUnit`) or to not test the `app_id/0` function (as it's pretty trivial anyways).

Comment: The problem is that these getters being used by quite a few functions and I am trying to keep all my tests asynchronous. José Valim had a good point against using mocking, but without them it seems like a dead end...

Comment: @Skylight My suggestion remains to not test the function, as it's very trivial (no params, very small body, very predictable behaviour). Mocking such a function is overhead IMO. If this function is used by many functions, bugs in it will probably pop out anyways :)

Comment: @Skylight I concur with whatyouhide.  Testing small, trivial functions of that sort is a bit of cargo cult engineering.  Spend your time on more important issues.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation, and ended up using something like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.ConfigTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  setup do
    previous_env = System.get_env()
    on_exit(fn -> System.put_env(previous_env) end)
  end

  test "I can change environment for this test only" do
    System.put_env("HOME", "/tmp")
    assert System.get_env("HOME") == "/tmp"
  end

  test "Should not affect other tests" do
    assert System.get_env("HOME") != "/tmp"
  end
end
```

Important stuff would be the `on_exit` callback and `async: false` definitions.

I'm not 100% sure it's safe, or even pretty TBH.

Answer (score 1):

As @whatyouhide said, you can't get around the fact that those variables are global so what I would do is isolate the issue:

- Isolate the `app_id` tests in their own test file using `async: false` and test this the way you already do;
- Do the same for all tests where the result really depends on the value of `app_id`;
- For all tests that use `app_id` but where the actual value of `app_id` doesn't impact the result, set a sensible value in the `setup_all` callback so that those are only set once for the whole test file.

This way, most of your tests can run async and only the ones where the result is directly dependant on the value of `app_id` are run non-async.

Answer (score 0):

What you may do is write shell code to call the tests.  Write shell code that sets the environment variable and then executes the test. Your shell code could use sed or something along those lines to modify the config.exs to either have the value or not have the value depending on how you wish to test.

The tests, as they stand right now, are adding almost no value. Right now you're effectively testing the `Application` module.

Also don't forget to test your code if neither place (either config.exs nor the environment variable) is set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Mock framework](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) you can do the following.

```
defmodule MyApp.ConfigTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false
  import Mock

  test "I can change specific environment for this test only" do
      env = System.get_env()
      with_mock(System, [:passthrough],
        get_env: fn
          "HOME" -> "/tmp"
          key -> Map.get(env, key)
        end
      ) do
     assert System.get_env("HOME") == "/tmp"
  end

  test "Should not affect other tests" do
    assert System.get_env("HOME") != "/tmp"
  end
end
```